# Can't define font-size on Chrome form autofilled text

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a pop-up with a form in it. I'm testing it on Chrome and am trying to work around the Chrome Autocomplete styling. I'm not trying to get rid of the Autocomplete, just trying to keep the styling that I wrote.
I managed to get rid of the styling of the background-color, border, and text color - now I just need to define a font-size on the autocompleted text.

You can see pictures of the correct and wrong font-size [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CrD6c.jpg).

I tried to define a font-size on the element's -webkit-autofill. It didn't work.

Also tried to define webkit-text-size-adjust, however it seems to no longer be supported.

```
input:-webkit-autofill,
input:-webkit-autofill:hover, 
input:-webkit-autofill:focus {
  webkit-text-size-adjust: 150%;
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

How come simply defining font-size doesn't work, when I can define other styling?

Comment: Can u plz add this in fiddle? or send the entire code

Comment: I'm unable to right now. However I will add it on a code bin as soon as possible. :-)

Comment: ok, but we need the real visual.. but surely, we will find a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is an old question, but I was able to solve this using the `input:-webkit-autofill::first-line` selector:

```
input:-webkit-autofill,
input:-webkit-autofill:hover,
input:-webkit-autofill:focus,
input:-webkit-autofill:active,
input:-webkit-autofill::first-line {
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

Comment: That seems to solve it. Haha, thanks for answering :)